# What is the optimal method for saving user settings in an SwiftUI (iOS)?

Tags: ios, swiftui, settings, appstorage

@AppStorage is not secure and Core Data is used to manage big amounts of data.

Comment: In my Apps I use CoreData beside storing a big amount of data, also for storing user settings. This way you can also sync them with iCloud if you need that. If you don't want to use Core Data I would suggest to use UserDefaults: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/storing-user-settings-with-userdefaults

Comment: Core data isn't secure either. You can store reasonably small amounts of data securely in the keychain

Comment: why do user settings need to be "secure"

Comment: Small insignificant (volume, etc) user settings can go in AppStorage, names, tokens, login info goes in Keychain. App state data like NavigationLink selection can go in SceneStorage.